# Returning value via javascript on form

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm very new to JavaScript and I'm trying to get a form that asks for a user's favorite number via form and then returns that value to them (just in the console for now). I also would like it to validate that the value entered was a number. Here is my code:

```
<div class="form">
  <form name="firstForm" action="#" onsubmit="results()">
    <input type="text" name="inputbox" placeholder="number"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
  </form>

<script>
function results(form) {
  var favNum = form.getElementByName("inputbox").value;
  if(isNaN(favNum)) {
   console.log("You didn't enter a number, silly goose!");
  }
 else {
    console.log("Your favorite number is: " + favNum);
  }
 }
 </script>
```

link for reference: radmint.github.io/wk3-bonus-4fun

and here's the repository github.com/radmint/wk3-bonus-4fun

Comment: One thing tho, I would personally use event listener for that, feels a bit tidier for me.

Comment: I'm definitely open for tidier code! I'll look into it, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youve had an issue in your code.

First, you are trying to call getElementByName on form which does not exist.

You need to call it on the document.

Second, its not called getElementByName but getElementsByName so you are missing plural there.

This is working example.

```
function results() {
var favNum = document.getElementsByName("inputbox")[0].value;
  if(isNaN(favNum)) {
   console.log("You didn't enter a number, silly goose!");
  }
 else {
    console.log("Your favorite number is: " + favNum);
  }
 }
```

EDIT: Have in mind that after the js will proceed your browser window can "refresh" and you will not see the output in console.

Comment: thank you! I'm trying it now. Here's the link for reference https://radmint.github.io/wk3-bonus-4fun/ and here's the repository https://github.com/radmint/wk3-bonus-4fun

Comment: Does it work for you? If so, please accept as an answer.

Comment: okay dope, I was waiting for github pages to update but got impatient and tested it locally and it works, so thank you so much! Do you know why it's adding the value and 'submit' to the URL? Is there anyway I can prevent this?

Comment: The simplest way is to change button from submit to button and simply instead of on submit use on click.